# creating a (simple?) photo gallery

Tags: ios, swift

I have started learning Swift and I created a very simple app - photo gallery, videos, webView for our website.

I'm following this tutorial on youtube: **https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JbPc62YWhPQ** and combined a few other ones to get that nice 3 column layout for the photo gallery to go along with it.

This works well for now, but when I click an image, I've to go back and select another image. I've been trying to find a way to swipe across and found this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LaWnv5sRpho

Unfortunately I can't seem to figure out how combine both. Maybe I've been googling for the wrong things? Can anyone help or direct me to a tutorial that could bridge these 2 things together?

They want something that functions similar to the native Photos app. Not sure how to swipe.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28696008/swipe-back-and-forth-through-array-of-images-swift

Comment: These links might help you . :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ztIBNHOm35E , https://github.com/TDAbboud/PhotosGalleryApp , https://github.com/Inspirato/SwiftPhotoGallery